# How to store image into the local storage using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm attempting to store the image from a `form` into my local storage path.

This is my controller:

```
class EmployeeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $img= Employee::all();
        return view('employee.index', compact("img"));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('employee.create');
    }

    public function store()
    {    
        request()->file('image')->store('employee');
        return view('employee.index');
    }
}
```

This is my view:

```
 <form method="POST" action="/employee" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="image">Image: </label>
        <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control">
        <button type="submit">Add Image</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm also using XAMPP and in my php.ini file I have enabled the `php_fileinfo.dll` extension.

but unfortunately I get an error

> Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available (Did you
>   enable the php_fileinfo extension?)

should I change something else in the php.ini file ?

**EDIT**

```
Route::get('/', 'EmployeeController@index');

Route::get('/employee/create', 'EmployeeController@create');

Route::post('/employee', 'EmployeeController@store');
```

Comment: Have you restarted apache?

Comment: yes i restarted apache and also my pc, didn't work

Comment: Is your fileinfo extension found in phpinfo?

Comment: yes its enabled. https://imgur.com/a/pBLYi

Comment: i get also a  TokenMismatchException even if i set the `csrf_field()` to the html form

Comment: Can you share your route details?

Comment: I edited my question and added the routes